# Checking parameters passed into function by array

Tags: php

I'm wrapping a model function in Yii 1.8 that has the signature:

```
public save($runValidation=true, array $attributes=NULL)
```

With a function:

```
public xSave(array $params)
```

That allows the addition of a flag and optional message that causes the wrapper function to throw an Exception in the case that the delegated `save()` function returns `false`.

I toyed with the idea of overwriting `save()` with:

```
public save(
  $runValidation=true,
  array $attributes=NULL,
  $exception_on_error=false,
  $exception_message=false
)
```

but would like to allow the specification of the last two parameters independently from the first and like the idea of allowing the extra readability of passing in an array with string keys.

I have so far:

```
/**
  * Enhanced save function.
  *   Delegates to standard model save to allow exceptions to be thrown
  *   in the case where the model was not saved.
 **/
public function xSave(array $params=array()){

  $_params=array(
    'run_validation'=>true,
    'attributes'=> null,
    'exception_on_failure'=>false,
    'exception_message'=>false,
  );

  array_merge($_params, $params);

  // Call the save method.
  $is_saved=$this->save($_params['run_validation'],$_params['attributes']);

  // Throw exception to if flag set and model not saved.
  if($_params['exception_on_failure'] && !$is_saved){

    // If no exception message was passed in, use the default.
    if($_params['exception_message'] === false){
      throw new CException('
        Could not '.($this->isNewRecord()?'create':'update').' '.get_class($this).';
        Errors: '.CJSON::encode($this->errors)
      );
    }

    // Else throw using the one provided.
    throw new CException($exception_message);
  }

  // Return result of standard save method.
  return $is_saved;
}
```

Firstly I'd like to know if this is a sensible choice, as I may well use it for other parts of the system. I'm currently not too worried about the typing of the parameters although I agree this could be an issue in the future.

Secondly I would also like the ability to throw an exception in the case that `$params` has a key that is not defined in `$_params` with a message specifying that key, and would like to do this as part of the `array_merge` if possible.

Comment: Have you thought about `func_get_args` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.func-get-args.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To 1), yes, passing arrays is the usual lame workaround in languages that don't support named arguments (see jQuery etc). With the new array syntax, this is even almost readable:

```
$some->save([
  $runValidation => true,
  $attributes => ['foo', 'bar']
]);
```

Inside a function, you can use [`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) to avoid ugly `$params[foobar]` references.

For better taste though, persuade [@NikiC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/385378/nikic) to get [this patch](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/named_params) ready ))

To 2), if you plan to use argument arrays systematically, consider a helper function like this:

```
function parseArgs($args, $defaults) {
    foreach($args as $k => $v) {
        if(!array_key_exists($k, $defaults))
            throw new Exception("invalid argument: $k");

        // might want to add some type checking, like
        // if(gettype($v) != gettype($defaults[$k])) bang!
    }
    return $args + $defaults;
}
```

Usage:

```
public function xSave(array $params=array()){

     extract(parseArgs($params, [
       'run_validation'=>true,
       'attributes'=> null,
       'exception_on_failure'=>false,
       'exception_message'=>false,
    ]));

    if ($run_validation)
        etc....
```

Comment: Yum, like the idea of named parameters! Didn't know about extract, but will look into it and the helper function. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Without seeing a benchmark, I would say this is slower than just using `array_diff()`. Of course there are thresholds in the array size and/or position of the "bad" element

Comment: @hek2mgl: given that arguments' lists are usually tiny (<10 elements), I don't think there will be any performance gain worth talking about. Plus, the loop is memory-friendly, unlike `array_keys` and `array_diff`.

Comment: @georg Yes argument lists are tiny, but in a web application there are *many* function/method calls. So I think it would be interesting to profile the difference. However, I don't wanted to be too picky and still I'm not sure whether I'm right or not. (would need to investigate)

Answer (score 1):

The decision to either use single parameters or parameter-arrays is opinion based. It depends on the situation. At least I would keep the design consistent across the whole project.

---

To decide if there had been unknown parameters passed, you can use `array_diff()`:

```
$a = array(
  'test' => 'foo',
  'name' => 'bar'
);

$b = array(
  'test' => 'foo',
  'name' => 'bar',
  'abcd' => '123'
);

$d = array_diff(
    array_keys($b), array_keys($a)
);

echo "The following keys can't be understood: " . implode(', ', $d) . PHP_EOL;
```

However, I would skip that check as it will not "harm" if there are unknown parameters.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking at doing it so that the first unrecognized key would be exceptioned rather than the whole parameter array. The unknown parameters can be harmful if someone calls the function with the wrong key.. for my example they think 'exception_on_failure' is 'exception_on_fail', this param would be ignored without the check with no error and the function would not perform as expected.

Comment: I expect `array_diff()` being faster than a custom foreach in most use cases. Sure, would need a benchmark to prove this

Comment: Apologies, I misread your solution.. I see now that only the unrecognized keys are printed.